# Agent job not getting triggered for private agent on VSTS

Tags: python, azure-devops, pyodbc, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a build pipeline with private agent.

On my private agent I have added ODBC connection to connect to Azure Databricks service. The connection was successful.

[image]

[image]

Build fails with below error:

```
2018-10-02T07:44:15.2532816Z   File "C:\agent\A\1\s\Read_Table.py", line 119, in from_hive
2018-10-02T07:44:15.2532816Z     hiveconn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MyAzureDatabricks_DSN",autocommit = True)  # TO CONNECT TO QA Environment
2018-10-02T07:44:15.2532816Z pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
2018-10-02T07:44:15.3624816Z ##[error]C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe failed with return code: 1
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: When I run into problems like this I like to log into the build server as the Service Account that is running the Private Agent and then executing everything, including the build and tests manually, as if you were the service account doing the same process as an automated build and test would do.  This can reveal security disconnects.  I know this is a System ODBC connection, so it should be available for all users, but try it as the Agent's service account instead of your personal login account?